# React Dynamic append using map

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react,

I am learning react, In this process I tried to create a for loop render using react. Were I am stuck in the following code

Below is my code

```
  <Container>
            <Row xs={3} md={4} lg={6}>
            {[...Array(numberOfCards)].map((e, i) => {
                return (
                  <Col className='mt-5' key={i+1}> 
                      <Card >
                          {/* <Card.Img top width="100%" src="/images/companylogo.png" alt="Card image cap"/> */}
                          <Card.Body>
                              <Card.Title tag="h5">Card title</Card.Title>
                              <Card.Subtitle tag="h6" className="mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</Card.Subtitle>
                              <Card.Text>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the
                                  card's
                                  content.</Card.Text>
                              <Button onClick={() =>addquantity({i+1},{email})}>Button</Button>
                          </Card.Body>
                      </Card>
                  </Col>
                )
            })}
            </Row>
        </Container>
```

here, In the Button Onclick event I am passing the "{i+1}"

[image]

Can you help me to understand what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the `addquantity` function definition so we may see what arguments it takes and how. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You should increment the value if "i" in your ""addquantity" function. With that you can `onClick={() =>addquantity(i, email)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are defining the function in the `onClick`, the variables are in scope and shouldn't be inserted using `{...}` formats.

This should work (note that `email` should be defined somewhere):

```js
         <Container>
            <Row xs={3} md={4} lg={6}>
            {[...Array(numberOfCards)].map((e, i) => {
                return (
                  <Col className='mt-5' key={i+1}> 
                      <Card >
                          {/* <Card.Img top width="100%" src="/images/companylogo.png" alt="Card image cap"/> */}
                          <Card.Body>
                              <Card.Title tag="h5">Card title</Card.Title>
                              <Card.Subtitle tag="h6" className="mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</Card.Subtitle>
                              <Card.Text>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the
                                  card's
                                  content.</Card.Text>
                              <Button onClick={() =>addquantity(i+1,email)}>Button</Button>
                          </Card.Body>
                      </Card>
                  </Col>
                )
            })}
            </Row>
        </Container>
```